# Select Candidates based on votes count permutations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have a question i am not sure which formulae fit for such scenario

Twenty people are voting for one of 5 candidates. They have secret ballot, each voter votes for one of 5 candidates. The result of an election is the number of votes for each of the candidate. How many possible results can this vote have?

Comment: Since we only care about how many votes each candidate receives, this is a [combinations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the following are equivalent:

- The number of integer solutions of 
  $$x_1+x_2+...+x_n=r, \ \ \ \ \  x_i\geq0$$
- Number of selections, with repetition, of size $r$ from a collections of size $n$.
- Number of ways $r$ identical objects can be distributed among $n$ distinct containers.

Let each candidate be $x_i$ for $i \in \{1,2,3,4,5 \}$.
Then you are looking for the number of nonnegative integer solutions for
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5 = 20.$$
This is equivalent to finding the number of selections, with repetition, of size $20$ from a collection of size $5$, which is given by
$$\binom{5+20-1}{20} = \binom{24}{20} = 10,626.$$
So you have $10,626$ possible results for the election. 
This is because you are not taking into account the identity of the voters, so the $20$ votes are counted as identical objects to be distributed among $5$ distinct "containers", which, in this case, would refer to the candidates.